# Should I avoid adding a clustered key to a table with high throughput

Tags: sql-server, database-design, index, primary-key

We have a SQL Server solution that has a table `dsStaging.Audit` that stores audit records created by a third party transactional database.  We use these audits to synchronise CRUD operations from the third party system into our SQL database.

```
CREATE TABLE [dsStaging].[Audit](
    [SyncExecutionId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [AuditDataGuid] [nvarchar](56) NOT NULL,
    [AuditDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [AuditDateTimeZone] [datetimeoffset](3) NULL,
    [AuditEventGroup] [nvarchar](56) NOT NULL,
    [TransactionId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [TransactionSequence] [int] NOT NULL,
    .
    ...
    .
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Audit] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SyncExecutionId] ASC,
    [TransactionId] ASC,
    [TransactionSequence] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

When the audits are processed, I want to move the audit records into a separate table `Processed.Audit`, ready for deletion after x days.

```
CREATE TABLE [Processed].[Audit](
    [SyncExecutionId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [AuditDataGuid] [nvarchar](56) NOT NULL,
    [AuditDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [AuditEventGroup] [nvarchar](56) NOT NULL,
    [TransactionId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [TransactionSequence] [int] NOT NULL,
    .
    ...
    .
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Processed_Audit] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [AuditDate] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

My main aim in moving audits out of staging and into processed is performance.  I need to make sure that the staging table is locked for as short a time as possible, so that any unprocessed audits can be processed as quickly as possible (fewer audits in the staging table = much faster processing).

We're looking at around **1.5m audit records** going through this process **every hour** in batches of about 10k.

The process for moving audits will fire roughly every 20-30 seconds.  The process for deleting `Processed.Audit` records will execute every hour and delete 1 hour's worth of audits from X days ago (typically around 7 days).

- Should I turn the `Processed.Audit` table into a clustered index?

Minimum version to be supported: **SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main reason I would want a clustered index in this scenario is this line:

> The process for deleting process.Audit records will execute every hour and delete an hours worth of audits from x days ago (typically around 7 days)

When you delete rows from a HEAP, data pages may not be deallocated unless the delete gets a table lock, or you provide a `WITH (TABLOCK)` hint to the delete query. You can probably imagine what that does to concurrency, though. Not good.

Note that the `TABLOCK` hint will not have this behavior if you're using RCSI or Snapshot Isolation.

Here's a quick example. Load up a small table:

```
USE tempdb;
SET NOCOUNT ON;

CREATE TABLE dbo.heap
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
    junk VARCHAR(1000)
);

INSERT dbo.heap (
    id, junk )
SELECT TOP 1000 x.n, REPLICATE('A', x.n % 1000)
FROM   (
           SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY @@ROWCOUNT ) AS n
           FROM   sys.messages AS m ) AS x;
```

Run a sanity check query to figure out how many pages are assigned to the heap, and to the nonclustered PK:

```
SELECT   OBJECT_NAME(i.object_id) AS table_name,
         i.name AS index_name,
         MAX(a.used_pages) AS leaf_me_alone
FROM     sys.indexes AS i
JOIN     sys.partitions AS p
ON p.object_id = i.object_id
   AND p.index_id = i.index_id
JOIN     sys.allocation_units AS a
ON a.container_id = p.partition_id
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(i.object_id) = 'heap'
GROUP BY i.object_id, i.index_id, i.name
ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME(i.object_id), i.index_id;
```

Results in this:

```
table_name  index_name  leaf_me_alone
heap        NULL        74
heap        PK__heap__  7
```

So, 74 pages in the heap, 7 pages in the NC PK.

Do some singleton deletes to clear out the table:

```
DECLARE @i INT = 1;

WHILE @i < 1000
    BEGIN

        DELETE h
        FROM  dbo.heap AS h
        WHERE h.id = @i;

        SET @i += 1;

        PRINT @i;

    END;
```

If you re-run the sanity check query, you'll get the same result.

Worse, if you query the table now, SQL will read [ALL OF THOSE BLANK PAGES](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1f2iu_9Z)!

```
SET STATISTICS TIME, IO ON 
SELECT *
FROM   dbo.heap AS h;
```

> Table 'heap'. Scan count 1, logical reads 67

So now not only is our table artificially large, but SQL now has a bunch of blank pages on disk and in memory and in backups and in DBCC CHECKDB and... well, you get the point.

> We're looking at around 1.5m audit records going through this process every hour

Heh heh heh! No fun.

Other options for getting pages deallocated from the heap are:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.heap
```

Which doesn't work for you, because you need to batch delete data.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.heap REBUILD;
```

Which would be painful for you at that table size, because it will rebuild all nonclustered indexes on the table at the same time.

Will the table re-use pages? Sometimes maybe sorta kinda.

```
DECLARE @id_max INT = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM dbo.heap AS h);

INSERT dbo.heap (
    id, junk )
SELECT TOP 5000 x.n + @id_max, REPLICATE('A', x.n % 1000)
FROM   (
           SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY @@ROWCOUNT ) AS n
           FROM   sys.messages AS m ) AS x;
```

Sanity check:

```
table_name  index_name  leaf_me_alone
heap        NULL        400
heap        PK__heap__  20
```

SELECT * query:

> Table 'heap'. Scan count 1, logical reads 392

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I would do it differently:

1. Table `dsStaging.Audit` without any constraints or indexes.
2. Move the records to middle table by switch partition or `sp_rename`.
3. Create index on the middle table to support the deleting process.
4. Move data from middle table into process Audit table. (delete into is recommended).
5. Drop middle table. The END.

I would consider to partition the `process.Audit` table and from middle table using switch partition feature.

Comment: Noting that partitioning is not supported by SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition (not included in Standard Edition until 2016 SP1)

Comment: Thanks I know but rename is still an option.

Comment: @itzikPaz thanks for the suggestion - can you give some reasoning for doing it this way over the methods discussed thus far?  btw: I'd prefer not to remove any indices or constraints from dsStaging.Audit because there are two processes that rely on them; the load of records into dsStaging.Audit and the processing of audits in dsStaging.Audit.

Comment: The main reason is . Any constraints or indexes in table dsstaging.Audit will  impact badly on inserting statement .