# How to reclaim the storage space used by a heap?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, storage

I have a table without a clustered index in SQL Server 2008R2 Standard with a lot of unused space, as shown in the following image:

[image]

How do I reclaim unused space from `MyTable`?

Said table is declared as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [RecordID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DocumentID] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [DocumentName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [DocumentOwner] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DocumentTemplate] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DocumentData] [ntext] NULL,
    [DocumentDate] [char](10) NULL,
    [DocumentTime] [char](10) NULL,
    [DocumentSize] [int] NULL,
    [DocumentUpdateVersion] [int] NULL,
    [SecondaryStorageURI] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [PreviousExportUri] [varchar](150) NULL
)
```

What steps should I follow to free unused space?

Comment: Are you looking for [DBCC CLEANTABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-cleantable-transact-sql)? If so, make sure to read the Best Practices paragraph on the documentation.

Comment: Does your table have a clustered index?

Comment: @RigertaDemiri that only works if you've dropped columns.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik, that is why I didn't post it as an answer :) And that's also what the "Best Practices" paragraph addresses. But there's not a lot of info on the question whether this is the case of not, you are right!

Comment: @RigertaDemiri I wish it worked under more circumstances.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik another thing to add as a comment at the new [blog post](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/09/put-sql-server-2018/):D

Comment: yes i do have Non-clustered index @sp_BlitzErik

Comment: @DAVID I'm asking about a clustered index.

Comment: no i do not have clustered index @sp_BlitzErik

Comment: @DAVID see my [answer here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186019/should-i-avoid-adding-a-clustered-key-to-a-table-with-high-throughput/186022#186022) for options.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If your table doesn't have a clustered index, then deletes don't deallocate empty pages by default.

Your options are:

- **ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable REBUILD** - which will take your table offline in Standard Edition, building a new copy of it with everything packed in nicely like sardines
- **Do your deletes with the TABLOCK hint** - which can prove problematic for concurrency, since as it indicates, will take out a table lock to do the deletes
- **Truncate the table** - which will deallocate all of the pages, not just the empty ones, so it has the unfortunate drawback of erasing all your data.
- **Put a clustered index on it** - if you frequently update & delete your data, then you should do as Beyonce says: put a clustered index on it. Otherwise, you end up with the empty-space problem that you're having now, plus the [forwarded-fetches problem](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/07/fix-forwarded-records/).

Comment: "as Beyonce says" was something deleted? Who is Beyonce (besides the singer)?

Comment: @jpmc26 "if you [frequently update and delete data from] it, then you shoulda put a [clustered index] on it"

Answer (score 2):

Given your table structure, the unused space is probably due to deletes of [DocumentData]. 
The fact that it's a heap isn't really important to this issue but it does simplify the solution a bit.

What I would do is rename the table, copy the data from the saved version into a new table and then drop the old one.

-- Step 1

```
sp_rename 'dbo.MyTable','dbo.MyTable_sav'
```

-- Step 2

```
SELECT [RecordID],
    [DocumentID],
    [DocumentName],
    [DocumentOwner],
    [DocumentTemplate],
    [DocumentData],
    [DocumentDate],
    [DocumentTime],
    [DocumentSize],
    [DocumentUpdateVersion] ,
    [SecondaryStorageURI] , 
    [PreviousExportUri]  
INTO dbo.MyTable
FROM dbo.MyTable_sav
```

-- confirm steps 1 and 2

```
DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable_sav
```

Comment: Psst - you forgot about his nonclustered indexes.

Comment: ALTER TABLE ... REBUILD would effectively accomplish the same thing, without having to shuffle things around manually. Extra steps to make are extra steps to mess up.